# Python line of best fit return value

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a linear line to my graph:
[image]

the x values of the red line(raw data) are:

```
array([  0.03591733,   0.16728212,   0.49537727,   0.96912459,
         1.        ,   1.        ,   1.11894521,   1.93042113,
         2.94284656,  10.98699942])
```

and the y values are

```
   array([ 0.0016241 ,  0.00151784,  0.00155586,  0.00174498,  0.00194872,
        0.00189413,  0.00208325,  0.00218074,  0.0021281 ,  0.00243127])
```

my code for the line of best fit is:

```
LineFit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(LineFit)
plt.plot(x,y,'r-')
plt.plot(x,p(y),'--')
plt.show()
```

However, my LineFit returns me

```
array([  7.03475069e-05,   1.76565292e-03])
```

which supposed to be interception and gradient according to the definition of polyfit (lower to higher order coefficient)
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html
but seems like its the opposite (gradient and interception) from the plot.
Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: It's possible the documentation is wrong. Do you also find this with higher-order fits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a different doc. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit:

> ...Fit a polynomial p(x) = p[0] * x**deg + ... + p[deg] of degree deg to points (x, y).

So in your example, it is p(x) = p[0] * x + p[1], which is exactly gradient and interception...